# How to point PHPUnit to a test DB?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I am using Symfony 2.6.9, Doctrine 2.3.6 and PHPUnit 3.7.38. I am trying to write unit tests for a service that interacts with the DB. I have successfully run the code in my development environment but when trying to run similar code in PHPUnit I get the following error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) \Tests\Service\ProcessorServiceTest::testProcessor
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
>   'INSERT INTO categories (name, description, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: categories
>
> /api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:47
>   /api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:71
>   /api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:598
>   /api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:263
>   /api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:929
>   /api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:318
>   /api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:355
>   //Tests/Service/ProcessorServiceTest.php:34
>
> Caused by PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such
>   table: categories

I have created a test database which is a copy of my development database (both MySQL) but suspect that PHPUnit is not pointed to that database correctly.  I have the following line in my phpunit.xml already:

```
<php>
    <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@DATABASEURL/test?charset=utf8mb4&amp;serverVersion=5.7" />
</php>
```

The test database should have all the tables set up already (I have already verified this via the console). Is there something else I need to do to point PHPUnit correctly?

For reference I wrote the tests using Symfony's KernelTestCase so my tests extend the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase class.

Comment: I'm afraid that the env variable is working only in recent Symfony versions (by the way, 2.6 is out of support). You can try to override your dbal configuration in test environment, so likely in your app/config/config_test.yml file

Comment: Thank you-modifying config_test.yml worked (will select if this is moved to answers)